# Lethal Solution

Tags: decanting-problems

You are given 4 identical glasses, completely filled with transparent, odorless liquids. Three of the liquids are pure water, and the fourth is poison, which is slightly heavier. If the water glasses weigh 250 grams each, and the poisoned glass weighs 260 grams, how can you figure out which one is which, using a measuring scale just once?

Comment: "Using the scale once.." as in taking a single reading? No.

Comment: what counts as a single use of the scale- weighing only one glass? or placing glasses on but only looking once (ie after all glasses are on)?

Comment: Do you know the value of A?

Comment: btw I hope it is not something like "I put all of them on the digital scale, then take one by one, when I dont see extra weight, that's the poisoned one" :)

Comment: If you know the values A and X, you can do it by introducing a fifth glass... if those are unknown this doesn't seem doable

Comment: I think the key here is "Using the scale once".  But it doesn't say how to use the scale.  We could take it apart and use it to build some electronic poison tester for all I know.

Comment: I could also take small sips from all four glasses over a period of years and build up an immunity.

Comment: "None of the glasses is poisoned. (It's the contents.)"

Comment: The currently accepted answer doesn't use [tag:lateral-thinking] much, so I think that tag should be removed from the question.

Comment: Hello TSLF, did you create the problem yourself, or it is a famous one? I think it is very nice.

Comment: I make other  puzzles, I wont post old puzzles

Comment: So this is your own? I believe that if you use some specific values for A and x, it will look better. Maybe A=200, x=10, the empty glasses 50 each or something.

Comment: Why not..that's fine with me..thanks

Comment: I added this puzzle to my website, posted it under your name. Let me know if that's not fine with you, and I will take it down. Cheers. puzzleprime.com/updates/2016106the-poisoned-glass

Comment: @Deusovi, I think that's a very neat puzzle and deserves higher rating, but the wording seems pretty bad. Please take a look at the version on my website and let me know if you think it is fine to edit it.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan: You don't have to ask *my* permission. I think you should go ahead and edit it - your phrasing is better IMO. TSLF, are you okay with that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's call our glasses $1,2,3$ and $4$. We are trying to find out which glass is poisoned, so we don't need the poisoned water!

Initially we have 4 glass of waters as shown below;

[image]

- Pour $1$ away and empty $1$ totally.

[image]

- Put a little water from $2$ to $1$ around less than half of the glass (very little amount of $2$) and put $2$ away,

[image]

- Likely, fill the rest of $1$ with $3$ (there will be much more $3$ in $1$ than $2$'s) and put $3$ away.

[image]

- Weight $1$ (filled with $2$ and $3$) and $4$ only.

As a result;

If the weight is exactly $500$:

> $1$ is poisoned

If the weight is exactly $510$:

> : $4$ is poisoned

If the weight is between $500$ and $505$:

> $2$ is poisoned

If the weight is between $505$ and $510$:

> $3$ is poisoned

Comment: Your criteria for glass 2 and glass 3 being poisoned are the same

Comment: why? I put only a little from 2.

Comment: "If the weight is 2A+(<0.5)x: 2 is poisoned" and If the weight is 2A+(<0.5)x: 3 is poisoned" both the weights are the same.

Comment: @dcfyj I always do little typos and you always find them!

Comment: This is all fine and dandy if we know what X is.

Comment: @John I believe A and x are known since it is said "weighing x grams" in the question. since OP confirmed the answer, I believe it is known.

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking we know it's heavier than A, but how much heavier was unknown.

Comment: where do you take illustrations from?

Comment: @John google? :)

Comment: That's a very nice solution, but I still don't understand why the problem has such a low score? It sounds like a good, classic puzzle.

Comment: If we're pouring it out, I would just do that.

Comment: I revisited your solution and it looks very nice with real 4 glasses..but do you really have to empty the Glass 1? If want a 35:65 ratio you can just

Comment: ..spill 35% and refill , saves you a move and water and environment.

Comment: @TSLF u dont have to, but it look much more clear in that way. this could be even solved with 5 glasses too by leaving a little 1 and fill with 2 and fill 2 with 3 as half.

Comment: I guess it is important to WARNING the readers not to try this at home.

Answer (score 16):

Yes.

> I take the glasses off the scale, pick up the scale and threaten to beat my 4 assistants with it unless they each drink a glass of water.  The one that dies drank the poison one.

Comment: Welcome to lateral thinking! hahaha

Comment: Some will complain you only need 3 assistants, but I say 4 is more elegant.

Comment: Actually, you only need 1 assistant. He'll only die if/when he drinks the poisoned glass.

Comment: OP made no reference as to how fast Poison X works.

Comment: I would put small fishes with your idea. Anyways your answer is funny +1

Comment: Plot twist, you put the poison in the water while sleep-walking.

Comment: doesn't work if they are strong kickboxers

Comment: I like this because it agrees with the title of the Q...

Answer (score 6):

It is very simple:

1. > Put all the water from the 4 glasses in a bucket.
2. > Mix all the water evenly.
3. > Put the water back in the glasses, evenly distributing it.
4. > Put the empty bucket in the scale, in order to pass the requirement of using the scale.

Now we know the solution:

5. > **All the 4 glasses are poisoned.**

With that, you can proceed to the plot twist:

6. > Grab 4 of your enemies to a death game where each one should drink a glass, telling them that one of them are poisoned. Watch all of them die.

Answer (score 3):

Going with Deep Thought's idea:

If we put all the glasses on the scale at once and consider the scale to no longer be used once the are all removed.

So

> Put all the glasses on the scale and remove them one at a time until the measured weight is no longer a multiple of A grams.

Once you've done that you'll know which glass was poisoned.

Alternatively:

> Pour all the glasses into a large beaker and you'll know where the poison is.

Answer (score 3):

If the solution is homogeneous then we can identify the correct glass. Throw 1/5 liquid from the 1st glass, 1/4 from the 2nd, 1/3 from the 3rd and 1/2 from the 4th. Now ideally we should have a total weight of 2.71A but since the poison solution is homogeneous we'll have a slight change in the weight. If {2.71-observed weight} has a ratio of 4:5 with X then the 1st glass is poisonous, if the ratio is 3:4 then the 2nd one and so on.

Answer (score 2):

> I slowly drink from each of the glasses in turn.  The one that poisons me is the poison one.  I don't need the scale.

EDIT: @Chris Cudmore beat me to this general idea by 1 minute!

Comment: @ChrisCudmore's answer does use the scale, and doesn't result in his death.

Answer (score 2):

If we don't know what X is, we can take four equal size (small?) water balloons and drop them into each solution.

> Which ever one ultimately settles just higher than bottom has the poison, provided there's not an amount so small as to be mostly unobservable. In that case, you may be able to see which one sinks the slowest.

Finally,

> Take all the glasses off the scale and measure the one that you think has the poison to verify your observation. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Digital scales work by testing electrical resistance.  Use it once to weigh all the water just to satisfy that requirement.  Then rip the components out to test the electrical resistance of the 4 fluids.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to find the poison by using the scale just once!

> Odds are you will fail though.
>
>  I just realized how important it is to ask for "a fail proof way" to do something.

Answer (score 0):

> Drink the glasses, wait to feel like I'm dying. Repeat. Zero uses of the scale.

Comment: I like your way of thinking. +1 for you. Nothing was said about staying alive. They did say however that you should use the scale one time.

Answer (score 0):

Take glasses 1 2 3 4 off the scale
Spill some of 2 then refill from 1..
Weigh mixture 2 with 3.  If reading:
 a bit > A+A : glass1 has it,
if a bit < A+A+x :glass2,
if=A+A+x :glass3,
=A+A :glass4
     *note: taking the 4 glasses at the same time with two hands needs caution

Comment: If the reading is greater than A+A, then it could be 1. But it could be 2. Or it could be 3. All you've determined is that it's not 4.

Comment: the purpose of spilling some of glass2 content is to make sufficient

difference on poison weight (e.i about 2% to 20% water volume).The scale can read milligram anyway 2%gram=20mg 98%gram=980mg.       Throwing the contents of glass1 ..is losing the evidence.

Comment: I understand now (based on the accepted answer) that the amount of poison was intended to be measurable. That was based on the original question where the amount of poison was X. With the revision of the question where the weight difference is made clear (10 grams), my comment no longer applies.

Answer (score 0):

Its the old bags of gold and scale riddle. With a new twist. But same solution applies.  1 cubic cm of water weighs 1 gram. Assuming i can zero the scale to elininate the weight of the vessel holding liquid and get a true weight of the liquid. Take one cm3 out if glass 1. Dump the rest. Put glass on scale and zero scale. (Not a weighing but reading scale by zering vessil)  Return the cm3 back to glass 1. Take 2 cm3 out of glass 2 and add to glass 1. Take 3 cm3 out if glass 3. And add to 1. Take 4 cm3 out of glass 4 and add to glass 1. You now have 10 cm3 in glass 1. Take your only weighing. You should have 10 grams and something. Your something is the poison. The something will be 4,3,2 or 1 unit of x over 10 grams. Which ever it is, the corresponding glass holds the poison.   Dont drink it.

Answer (score -1):

Well it is marked "lateral-thinking" so if we stretch the meaning of

> "use the scale once"

a little bit, then it's not hard.

> Specifically, once we've used the scale, we take the glasses off the scale, of course. But we take them off in a certain order.

I'm sure everyone can figure it out now, but if you are impatient:

> Put two glasses on each side. Now, one side is heavier. First, take a glass off the lighter side. Then take a glass off the heavier side. If it is now balanced, the glass you took off the heavier side is poisoned. If it is still unbalanced, the glass still on the heavier side is poisoned.

Comment: It's a digital scale, not a balance.

Comment: it is a digital scale showing as number, not sides on it.

Comment: Ahh, missed that point.

Comment: using scale means reading the digital display..once

Comment: Or, you could leverage the use of the word "Can" in the question.  Yes, you *can* by just putting 1 glass on the scale, but maybe not 100% of the time.

Answer (score -2):

My one:

> Boils each 4 glasses at 100ºC .A posion in a glass doesnot vapourize

Comment: "poison does not vapourize"  wat

Comment: @deepthought Answers are correct. Generalities are fun.